# How to create a new database in SAP HANA command line (HDBSQL)?

Tags: hana

I am new to hdbsql and I have logged in to the SAP HANA Server and logged in to the hdbsql terminal as a HDB admin user (SYSTEM).

1. Is it good to create databases as admin user? If not how to create a new user for hdbsql?
2. How to create a new Database in command line? (Will this work `CREATE DATABASE dbname;`?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE DATABASE as a command only applies if you are using a multi database container setup. 
As this question really is more about the concepts of HANA database administration, I highly recommend to invest the time to read the documentation or watch a video from the HANA academy on youtube. 
I'm pretty sure this will get you up to speed quicker than asking single questions one by one.

Comment: Thanks but Most of the documentation and videos are based on HANA STUDIO where I am working at the command line(OS level). And when I am logged in as a user I get the **insufficient privilege not authorized** error showing up.Could you help me out?

Comment: If your user doesn't have the required privileges then it makes no difference if yoy use hdbsql or HANA studio or the WEB based tools. You need to get the sufficient privileges in any case.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have now got the privileges and able to access the **HDBSQL**.

Answer (score 0):

*Did you try 'create database'?*

You should use 
`CREATE SCHEMA <schema_name> [OWNED BY <user_name>]`.

More info on HANA queries/statements/functions can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/ff532c751910148657c32fe3431a9f/content.htm?frameset=/en/20/9ce8cd75191014bcd59c2b379a17c9/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=4&show_children=false).

Comment: I think as now I am in admin user mode  I should  try "create user mydbuser password mypassword" and then login as a user and then only try create database.Am I on the right path? Thanks.