# Can we create database in SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, hana

I am new to SAP HANA and I created a new user in SAP HANA hdbsql (command line) by

```
hdbsql=> create user username password password
```

Now I am trying to create a database with the query,

```
hdbsql=> CREATE DATABASE dbname
```

But I could not create the database. Could anyone provide a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new database in SAP HANA command line (HDBSQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657365/how-to-create-a-new-database-in-sap-hana-command-line-hdbsql)

Answer (score 3):

The SAP HANA database does not have the concept of different databases, but of schemas instead. So if you want to create a "container" for your tables, you have to create your own schema. The definition of the CREATE SCHEMA statement can be found here:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d4ecad7519101497d192700ce5f3df/content.htm

This is also a good reference for the SQL syntax of HANA. The most easiest query to create a schema would look like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA schemaname
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two document which shows HANA can create database.

https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hxe-ua-dbfundamentals-tenantdb.html

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/65cd51970fa44f36a4c9083915cf3162.html